# Stop reflecting model of each other if same controller used twice in a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used mvc partial control in my page twice for search functionality.
It has it own controller to search, so my page has two controller with same name.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="SetSearchParam()">
     <div id="search1">
        @Html.Partial("_SearchPartial") // say it search1
        // some other code to show search results
        // ....               
        // ..
     </div>
     <div id="search2">
        @Html.Partial("_SearchPartial") // say it search2
        // some other code to show search results
        // ....               
        // ..
     </div>
</div>
```

This is _SearchPartial:

```
<form name="SearchCommon">
    <div ng-model="search" ng-controller="SearchPartialController">
            <div>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Stock" ng-model="search.Stock" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Make" ng-model="search.Make" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Year" ng-model="search.Year" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" ng-click="searchdata(search)" />
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now on init of `MainController` , i set the `search` model value in `SetSearchParam()` method like below:

```
$scope.SetSearchParam = function(){
   var s = {};
   s.Make = "Test";
   s.Year = "2012";
   s.Stock = "5"

   $scope.search = s; 
};
```

As `search` model is used in `SearchPartialController`, and page has two search control, value of `s` will be set in both partial controller. Also when i change params in search1, it will reflect search2.

I want that those search params only set for search1, not for search2.
When i change search1 params , it should not reflect the search2 or vice versa.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should initialize your filter(**search**) before your function.

Controller:

```
$scope.search1 = { Make : "Test", Year: "2012", Stock : "5" };
$scope.searchdata = function(search){console.log(search);};
```

Your view:

```
<body ng-controller="SearchPartialController">
    <form ng-submit="searchdata(search1)">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Stock" ng-model="search1.Stock" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Make" ng-model="search1.Make" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Year" ng-model="search1.Year" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                    Save
        </button>
    </form >
</body>
```